# Querying related model-attributes in django

Tags: python, django, modelattribute

I have the following  custom user model arrangement.

````
```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    student = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=False, default='')
class TeacherProfile(models.Model):
    teacher = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=False, default='')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='')

```
````

I am able to a query the students based on the location of their teacher (current user).

```
Student.objects.filter(location=request.user.teacher.location)
```

I can also query the user model & find all teachers/students

```
    User.objects.filter(is_teacher=True)
```

**QUESTION:**
Without relying on the profile models (Student & Teacher) How can I extend the query on abstractuser using profile attributes.

[X]-This is wrong but the idea is something like;

```
    User.objects.filter(is_teacher=True).filter(is_teacher.location=newyork)
```

Comment: Yoour `TeacherProfile` does not seem to have a `location` field?

Comment: apologies. the location field is similar to the one in studentprofile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the `OneToOneField` in reverse:

```
User.objects.filter(teacherprofile__location='newyork')
```

You thus do not need to store `is_teacher` and `is_student` explicitly. You can simply filter `Student`s with:

```
# Users with a related StudentProfile record
User.objects.filter(studentprofile__isnull=False)
```